# Phenomenon of omitting the head noun of a relative clause

Tags: relative-clauses, ellipsis, omission

Take this dialogue for example, where A and B talk about a certain 田中さん:

A: ところで田中さんって覚えてる？
B: あ、このあいだパーティーにいた？

I made it up, so please excuse any unnatural aspects. The important part is B's answer. Rather than "Ah, he/she was at the party the other day?", it feels more like "Ah, the one who was at the party the other day?", like there is a 人 or やつ at the end of the sentence that was omitted.

Although I think I've seen this pattern quite a few times, I don't remember having seen any discussion about it. If it exists (and I'm not imagining things), does it have a name and is there anything notable about it?

Comment: The head noun comes at the end of the noun phrase. If it's obvious from context, why not omit it? That's how native speakers see it. Nothing notable there.